# Shopify app for altering the default checkout procedure

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I need to create a solution for altering the **checkout process**.
Better said, I need to add some functionality to it with a remote app (I am not sure if this is the right way to do it).
Mainly, what is needed represents a process that calls an **external API**, using a private API key from a delivery company, that registers a pick-up from the buyers house and sends the product to our headquarters.The process should be started when the user completes the entire checkout system from shopify, **after payment**.
After that, some AWB should be returned to the users checkout page, or some response regarding the creation of the pick up.
My question is, let's say, using some language like javascript with node and Koa or express, **how one can achieve that?** I can't find any tutorials or something that would help me do this.

Comment: You can do this by adding custom scripts at the checkout page/process, but you would need a Shopify Plus account for that, otherwise there is no direct solution. Ref: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor#:~:text=Scripts%20and%20the%20Script%20Editor%20app%20are%20available%20to%20Shopify%20Plus%20merchants%20only.

Comment: Are you making your own private app to handle this? If so, it sounds like you want to make an app that subscribes to the "Order Created" webhook event and would take that information to send the required data to your external API.  https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/webhook#top

Comment: I don't really understand how the private apps work :)) but I will research that. I think the solution proposed by Dave should accomplish my scope.